# How to use multi-generics in modules？

Tags: kotlin, generics

In java, i hava code like below:

```
public class GenericTest {
    private static final GenericTest instance = new GenericTest();
    IRequirement requirement;
    public static GenericTest getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public class ClassA {}

    public interface InterfaceA {}

    public void init(IRequirement requirement){
        this.requirement = requirement;
    }

    public interface IRequirement {
        <T extends ClassA & InterfaceA> T supply();
    }

    class ClassB {
        void doSomeThing() {
            ClassA a = requirement.supply();
            InterfaceA ia = requirement.supply();
        }
    }
}
```

I can get `ClassA` or `InterfaceA` instance according to my needs.
But in kotlin, same codes like below:

```
open class ClassA(val name: String) {
    fun function1() {}

    fun function2() {}
}

interface InterfaceA {
    fun iFunction1()
}

class ModuleX private constructor() {
    var requirement: IRequirement? = null

    companion object {
        val instance = ModuleX()
    }

    fun init(requirement: IRequirement) {
        instance.requirement = requirement
    }

    interface IRequirement {
        fun <T> supply(): T where T : ClassA, T : InterfaceA
    }
}

object ClassB {
    inline fun <reified T> doSomeThing() where T : ClassA, T : InterfaceA{
        val require = ModuleX.instance.requirement?.supply<T>()
        require?.function1()
        require?.iFunction1()
    }

    fun doAnotherThing() {
        // IDE give an error when calling supply()
        val require = ModuleX.instance.requirement?.supply()
        require?.function1()
        require?.iFunction1()
    }
}
```

I must specify the actual type of the generic, or use the generic method, otherwise I will not be able to use the `IRequirement` in the code above, such as in `ClassB.doAnotherThing()` where IDE give an error "Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun  supply( ): T where T : InterfaceAPlease specify it explicitly."

My question is: In my module, it is required to provide a class that extends ClassA and implements InterfaceAd, but the module does not know the exact type of the class because it is outside the module. How should I use generics in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun doAnotherThing() {
    val require: Any? = ModuleX.instance.requirement?.supply()
    if (require != null) {
        (require as ClassA).function1()
        (require as InterfaceA).iFunction1()
    }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work，IDE show an error "Type parameter bound for T in fun <T : ClassA> supply( ): T where T : InterfaceA is not satisfied: inferred type Any? is not a subtype of ClassA" for `ModuleX.instance.requirement?.supply()` and there is a red line under the `supply()` code

Comment: You are right. The error went away after updating kotlin version to 1.4.  Thanks a lot~~